# Can we write avro files to dynamically created GCS buckets(based on tenantID)?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Basically what i am trying to do is, create GCS bucket based on tenantID(comes as part of event) and write these events using FileIO.writeDynamic using dynamic filenaming in google dataflow job.

The issue I am facing is

```
srcEvents.apply("Window", Window
                        .<MyEvent>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(60))))
                        .apply("WriteAvro", FileIO.<MyEventDestination, MyEvent>writeDynamic()
                                        .by(groupFn).via(outputFn, sinkFn)
                                        **.to()** // what to pass as here as i want it to be based on event.getTenantId (gs://test-123)
                                        .withDestinationCoder(destinationCoder)
                                        .withNumShards(100).withNaming(namingFn));
```

I am creating gcs bucket prior to the above by calling `PTranform of srcEvents`

Comment: Inside the to() method you should write the folder/bucket you want to save your files. [Here](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.3.0/index.html?org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.html) it is the documentation for writeDynamic(), you can find usage examples. Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: YEs i am aware that we need to give the directory path of the GCS bucket.. My question is how i generate the name of the bucket dynamically using tenantId?

Comment: I think the .to() method only works on one static directory defined at pipeline construction time, so it doesn't work for this use case. But maybe you could try prefixing the filenames with the bucket+directory structure you want, since that's done per element. (See this article: https://medium.com/@imrenagi/writing-date-partitioned-files-into-google-cloud-storage-with-cloud-dataflow-50ee1d5c03ed). If that works it should be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by using withTempDirectory option where i provided temp gcs bucket path and the use File Naming to build dynamic bucket path per domain

> `srcEvents.apply("Window", Window
>                           .<MyEvent>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(60))))
>                           .apply("WriteAvro", FileIO.<MyEventDestination, MyEvent>writeDynamic()
>                                           .by(groupFn).via(outputFn, sinkFn)
>                                           .withTempDirectory("gs://temp-blah/")
>                                           .withDestinationCoder(destinationCoder)
>                                           .withNumShards(100).withNaming(namingFn));
>   namingFn  to build filename gs://domain-123/2020-05-01/event.avro`